# Does Ping support multiple Audience restriction values in SAML?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, pingfederate

Using PING as my identity provider do I have an option to set multiple audience values (in the service provider configuration I add for my application) so they will be returned within AudienceRestriction element of the SAML assertion?
As I see PING adds issuer value as audience and nothing else.

Example condition element

```
<ns2:Conditions NotBefore="2011-01-10T20:52:56Z" NotOnOrAfter="2011-01-10T20:54:56Z">
  <ns2:AudienceRestriction>
    <ns2:Audience>urn:saml2:partnerspid</ns2:Audience>
  </ns2:AudienceRestriction>
  <ns2:AudienceRestriction>
    <ns2:Audience>Audience-IDP</ns2:Audience>
  </ns2:AudienceRestriction>
</ns2:Conditions>
```

Comment: Please provide an example response/assertion of what it is that you are looking for and reason... There's generally no reason to have multiple values returned.

Comment: Hi, I have added an example of what I'm looking for. I use this assertion in Oauth2 saml grant type flow. SP sends the assertion to token endpoint and get the access token. In validation, token endpoint checks whether SAML assertion contains it's own endpoint Alias as an Audience value. This is not same as the SP entityID. Therefore validation fails when assertion does not contain the required audience.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to be running PingFed 8.0+ for this to work, which is where Ping began allowing the customization of request and response XML. You should read more on that subject in their [documentation](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf83/index.shtml#adminGuide/concept/customizingAssertionsAndAuthenticationRequests.html).

Using this:

```
#AssertionType.getConditions().addNewAudienceRestriction().addAudience("whatever:eh")
```

will give you something like the following element:

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-03-24T20:23:55.341Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-03-24T20:38:55.341Z">
  <saml:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml:Audience>pingfederate:default:entityId</saml:Audience>
  </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  <saml:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml:Audience>whatever:eh</saml:Audience>
  </saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
```

However, SAML spec ([SAML-CORE-2.0, 2.5.1.4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf#page=23)) states:

> Note that multiple  elements MAY be included in a
>   single assertion, and each MUST be evaluated independently. The effect
>   of this requirement and the preceding definition is that within a
>   given condition, the audiences form a disjunction (an "OR") while
>   multiple conditions form a conjunction (an "AND").

So, in that format that you are talking about, you will get an "AND". It's highly unlikely that your partner will be able to fulfill both, so I think you may be looking for an "OR". If that's the case, you'll want to use the following:

```
#AssertionType.getConditions().getAudienceRestrictionArray(0).addAudience("whatever:eh")
```

Which should produce something like:

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-03-24T20:20:37.046Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-03-24T20:35:37.046Z">
  <saml:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml:Audience>pingfederate:default:entityId</saml:Audience>
    <saml:Audience>whatever:eh</saml:Audience>
  </saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
```

Comment: I may need glasses but it looks like you've pasted the same snippets twice (except for one character in the first audience value)...

Comment: Nice catch, @HansZ.! Fixed!

Comment: seems you guys may still need me over there ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes in my case I need to use *#AssertionType.getConditions().getAudienceRestrictionArray(0).addAudience("whatever:eh")*. However I do not have the required version yet. Will test once i get my hands on it.